# Ansible: copy multiple files to separate multiple destinations using patterns

Tags: ansible

I have the following files in the controller node:

```
config1.xml
config2.xml
hostfileA
hostfileB
setup1.conf
setup2.conf
```

I would like to copy the files to specific directories, depending on their filenames.

Example:

- copy all `config*.xml` files to `/opt/app/xmlconfig/`
- copy all `hostfile*` files to `/opt/app/hostfiles/`
- copy all `setup*.conf` files to `/opt/app/config/`

The closest I got to achieving this is with the following task

```
- name: Copy configuration files to remote servers
  copy:
    src: /tmp/{{ item.src }}
    dest: {{ item.dest }}
  with_fileglob:
    - { src: "config.*.xml", dest: "/opt/app/xmlconfig/" }
    - { src: "hostfile*", dest: "/opt/app/hostfiles/" }
    - { src: "setup*.conf", dest: "/opt/app/config/" }
```

The problem is, `with_fileglob` doesn't seem to support multiple items, and `with_items`, doesn't seem to support patterns.

Of course, I can create 3 separate `copy` tasks for each pattern-destination combination with the help of `with_fileglob`, but maybe there is a more efficient way to do it in 1 task instead of 3.

Looking forward to any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: There's a long ignored bug on this: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/37088 Any workaround is likely to be overly complicated. Honestly, I would just use three tasks.

Comment: I ended up using 3 separate tasks.

Comment: That's not an ansible bug. You're using a lookup that expects a list of strings and you're passing it a list of dictionaries. Why would you even expect that to work?

Comment: "Bug report" might be a more approriate term